# Can someone translate these lyrics in English?

Tags: translation, meaning, mandarin, lyrics, songs

> 爱恨廉价 似苍苍蒹葭
>
> 苦艾后劲 皆贪共与他
>
> 望光亮 两世皆行走潇洒
>
> 破万枷 散馀霞 众相皆渡他

Ref [众相渡他·2020肖战生贺原创曲](https://forums.huaren.us/showtopic.html?topicid=2380658&&fid=358&postid=85639367)

I used Google Translate and a dictionary to find the meaning, but it doesn't make sense.

Comment: This lyric use a mixed language of 文言文 and 普通话. Me as a native cannot understand most of it. This song is written by a fan for a pop star named 肖战. I am not a fan of him, but he is well known by his fan club. So, you can post a question in his 贴吧. His fans there will probably be willing to help.

Answer (score 2):

爱恨廉价 - **Love and hate are cheap**

- *love and hate here represent human emotions*; 'cheap' (easily be bought) implies 'can easily change'*

似苍苍蒹葭 - **Like a thick, thick reed field**

- *[蒹葭苍苍](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%92%B9%E8%91%AD%E8%8B%8D%E8%8B%8D/7886600) 《诗经·国风·秦风》中诗 (came from a classical Chinese literature 《Book of poetry》*)

苦艾后劲 - **like absinthe's strong aftertaste**

皆贪共与他 - All because of greed to be with him (*贪 = greed = strong desire*)

望光亮 - **Looking at the light**

两世皆行走潇洒 - chicly traveling in  both worlds (*two worlds refer to the living world and the afterworld*)

破万枷 - **breaking all shackles**

散馀霞 - **scatter the sunset cloud** (*the remaining sunlight at the dusk shines on the clouds make them seems red*)

众相皆渡他 - **Everything in the universe enlightens him**

- *相 is a Buddhism term for 'form'; 众相 means 'all forms'. It can be loosely translated as 'the universe'; 渡 is a Buddhism term for 'to enlighten')*